# Select count long query time

Tags: mysql, database, bigdata

3 million table records, select count query time is 0.6 seconds

3.2 million table records, select count query time is 8.4 seconds (200,000 new records)

3 million table records, select count query time is 8.4 seconds (delete 200,000 records)

1.2 million table records, select count query time is 9.7 seconds (more than 200,000 records deleted)

Data are normal when they are less than 3 million.
Insert 200,000 data at a time, execute multiple times, and delete tests. MySQL 5.6, Windows 10

```
select count(1) from t_node;
delete from t_Node limit 200000;
insert into t_node select * from t_node limit 200000;
```

I want select count query time < 1s

Comment: Does your table have appropriate indexes or table partitions?

Comment: thank you, 5 million data, select count 0.6s

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, that's about 10x difference.  It sounds like the data is bigger than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  Sometimes the `SELECT` runs mostly in RAM (CPU-bound at 0.6s), sometimes it runs mostly from disk (I/O-bound at 8-10s).

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and RAM size.  Also, do the `SHOW TABLE STATUS` before and after the delete+insert.